# Changing Base URL in Magento

Tags: magento, content-management-system, php

I am moving a magento store from mydomaintest.com to mydomain.com.

When I say move, in this instance, we simply used the Cpanel to Modify Account and changed the Domain Name from mydomaintest.com to mydomain.com.

Then using the advice found in forums I used PHPMyAdmin to update the Magento Core Config table to the new BaseURL for both Secure and Unsecure url's.

After doing this I deleted all files in /var/cache.

Trying to access the site by domain name or IP is providing the following error:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/mydomain/public_html/errors/report.php' (include_path='/home/mydomain/public_html/app/code/local:/home/mydomain/public_html/app/code/community:/home/mydomain/public_html/app/code/core:/home/mydomain/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mydomain/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 847

Please help, we are trying to move live today and can't seem to figure this one out.

Thanks!
John

Comment: 'Magento Core Config table' is this the core_config_data table?

Comment: Correct, that is what I modified

Comment: Did you also change the name of the directory?

Comment: Maybe this is a permissions issue. chmod -R 777 errors/ && chmod -R 777 var/cache/ && chmod -R var/session/ - This 777 is to try to figure out if this is a permission issue. Fine tuning them maybe required once you're sure this is permission issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Index management and Reindex data as it also contain the url rewrites. Also be sure to check System > Cache Management (some versions still have that) and flush all cache as var/cache is not the only caching location. The zend components save their cache in the tmp folder.

Comment: I can't get into the Admin...same error message as above in my post.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Magento running with Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.10

Make sure that MySQL module for PHP is install:

```
dpkg --list | grep php5-mysql
```

If it is not listed, you need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case we get this message because someone deleted the "error" folder - the site works fine until an error happens.

Once we restored the folder (and make sure PHP can access it), we see the normal Magento error page.
If you don't have the folder you can [download Magento](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download) and extract it from the archive.